# Cannot add Pinterest as cocoapods

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, pinterest

I'm trying to add `pod 'Pinterest-iOS', '~> 2.3'` to Swift 2.0 project, but no success. **Cocoapods** does not produce any framework or other product for this pod. Pinterest `pod` itself look strange:

[image]

Any thoughts?
**Cocoapods** 0.38.2

Comment: Can you show us your podfile? Maybe it's missing the "use_frameworks!" line at the beginning

Comment: it's definitely present

Comment: same to me . Looks lke Podfile is not right in this version

Comment: https://github.com/FarisAlbalawi/PinterestUISwift